# phony for targets with variable name using percent sign

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that is using %.target. I am wondering how I could add those to .PHONY.

Simplified, this might look like this.

```
%.build:
    docker build -t $* .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you want to do but if what you want is for any command line goal that matches the pattern `%.build` to be treated as phony you can add this to your makefile:

```
.PHONY: $(filter %.build,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

Comment: Yes, I want to add everything thats matching the pattern to .PHONY. i.e foo.build and bar.build.